# Kubernetes Deployment Hanging

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

Following the Deployment example in the docs. I'm trying to deploy the example nginx. With the following config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

So far, the deployment always hangs. I tried to see if for any reason I needed a pod named nginx to be deployed already. That didn't solve the problem.

```
$ sudo kubectl get deployments
NAME               UPDATEDREPLICAS   AGE
nginx-deployment   0/3               34m

$ sudo kubectl describe deployments
Name:                           nginx-deployment
Namespace:                      default
CreationTimestamp:              Sat, 30 Jan 2016 06:03:47 +0000
Labels:                         app=nginx
Selector:                       app=nginx
Replicas:                       0 updated / 3 total
StrategyType:                   RollingUpdate
RollingUpdateStrategy:          1 max unavailable, 1 max surge, 0 min ready    seconds
OldReplicationControllers:      nginx (2/2 replicas created)
NewReplicationController:       <none>
No events.
```

When I check the events from kubernetes I see no events which belong to this deployment. Has anyone experienced this before?

The versions are as followed:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.3", GitCommit:"6a81b50c7e97bbe0ade075de55ab4fa34f049dc2", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.3", GitCommit:"6a81b50c7e97bbe0ade075de55ab4fa34f049dc2", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: Do you have another controller (like an rc) fighting with the deployment pods? i.e an rc with selector=app:nginx might be trying to scale pods up while the deployment rc is trying to scale pods with the same label down.

Comment: Wouldn't that show up in events though? I added an rc later with the same label since I thought it might need a pod already in existence to run this properly...

Comment: That should show up in the events of the rc, but events are gc'd so they won't be around for too long. I'm not sure the fighting will show up in the events of the deployment itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer from the [issues page](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20381)

In order to get the deployments to work after you enable it and restart the kube-apiserver, you must also restart the kube-controller-manager.

Comment: how to restart apiserver and controller manager?

Answer (score 7):

If the deployment is not creating any pods you could have a look at the events an error might be reported there for example:

```
kubectl get events --all-namespaces                         
NAMESPACE   LASTSEEN   FIRSTSEEN   COUNT     NAME                   KIND         SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON         SOURCE                    MESSAGE
default     8m         2d          415       wordpress              Ingress                  Normal    Service        loadbalancer-controller   no user specified default backend, using system default
kube-lego   2m         8h          49        kube-lego-7c66c7fddf   ReplicaSet               Warning   FailedCreate   replicaset-controller     Error creating: pods "kube-lego-7c66c7fddf-" is forbidden: service account kube-lego/kube-lego2-kube-lego was not found, retry after the service account is created
```

Also have a look at `kubectl get rs --all-namespaces`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what is wrong with command `kubectl describe pod name_of_your_pod`

Comment: It's not a pod, its a deployment. No events are showing up, doesn't seem like its even trying to create anything.